# Trouble Deploying AWS Lambda Function from PyCharm - Stuck at "Fetching Stacks"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pycharm

I'm attempting to deploy a Lambda function on AWS using PyCharm. I've correctly configured PyCharm, and the function works locally on Docker. However, when I click "Sync Serverless Application," it hangs on "Fetching Stacks" for a few seconds, and then nothing happens. There are no error messages, and the S3 stacks screen doesn't appear. I've tried different versions of PyCharm and installed SAM using brew: SAM CLI, version 1.95.0.

My IAM permissions are as follows:

- AmazonS3FullAccess
- WSLambda_FullAccess

If I navigate to the Lambda section in PyCharm, I can see other functions that have been successfully deployed (from another laptop), so I believe the configuration is correct.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: The permissions you've listed are for S3 and Lambda, which are fine for deployment purposes. However, CloudFormation is used by SAM for deploying serverless applications, so you might want to ensure you also have AWSCloudFormationFullAccess permissions.